# Missing method in mscorlib.dll included in apk

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an obfuscated application in Monodroid and my problem is that the mscorlib assembly included in apk doesn't implements the method System.String.Intern() and my application doesn't work.

My obfuscator calls this method to obfuscate strings and I get a MissingMethodException. This method doesn't exists in the assembly included in apk but strangely it does exists in myproject/obj/release/assemblies/mscorlib.dll

These files are quite different. If I put the file myproject/obj/release/assemblies/mscorlib.dll in apk it works but this solution is a bad solution because the app fails in other point causing TypeLoadException because of the change of the dll.

Can anyone tell me why monodroid uses the mscorlib reduced file and an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you using `String.Intern()`? It seems rather odd that it would be removed, unless you're invoking it via Reflection (and thus the linker won't "see" your use).

Comment: I saw with Reflector that assembly mscorlib.dll included in apk doesn't use String.Intern() method. It seems that every .net obfuscator use this call to obfuscate strings. Could you verify if some mono apk contains this method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why monodroid uses the mscorlib reduced file and an alternative solution?

The smaller file is used to reduce application size by [linking the assemblies](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/linking). Linking can be brittle, as the linker doesn't trace runtime behavior. For example, using `Type.GetType("Foo")` will not preserve the type `Foo`, and thus the linker may remove it if it's not otherwise referenced.

`obj\Release\assemblies\mscorlib.dll` is the source assembly. `obj\Release\android/assets/mscorlib.dll` is the linked (smaller) assembly, which is included in the `.apk`.

If your obfuscator is directly using `String.Intern()`, this may suggest a bug in the linker. However, if your obfuscator is using Reflection (e.g. `Type.GetMethod()`), then this would be expected behavior. To fix it, you explicitly use `String.Intern()` [within a falseflag block](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/linking#falseflag) so that the method is preserved.

Comment: You were right. If I use it explicitly, the linked assembly contains this method and it works. Very helpful.
Thanks.